# machine learning model linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have made this linear regression model, and I have a huge problem. Why do I get negative values in my predicted values?when I do not have any negative values in my dataset?

So I do not have any idea why I get negative predicted values in my linear regression model.

```
import numpy as np # linær algebra
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.experimental import enable_hist_gradient_boosting
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
%matplotlib inline
```

```
!rm -r machine-learning/  # first remove folder, if present
!git clone https://github.com/Emmsiiii/fskning
```

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv("fskning/Data cleaned.csv", delimiter=";")
```

```
dataFrame.head()
```

```
X = dataFrame.astype(object)
y = dataFrame.astype(object)
y.info()
```

```
X = dataFrame[['Alder','Eksponeringer','Køn']]
y = dataFrame['CPM (pris pr. 1000 eksponeringer)']
```

```
X = pd.get_dummies(X)
y = pd.get_dummies(y)
```

```
X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)
```

```
reg_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

```
reg_model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
print('Intercept: ',reg_model.intercept_)

list(zip(X, reg_model.coef_))
```

```
y_pred= reg_model.predict(X_test)
x_pred= reg_model.predict(X_train)
```

```
y_pred= pd.DataFrame(reg_model.predict(X_test))
x_pred= pd.DataFrame(reg_model.predict(X_train))
```

```
reg_model_diff = ({'Actual value': y_test, 'Predicted value': y_pred})
reg_model_diff
```

```
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)
print("The mean sqaured error is: {:.2f}".format(mse))
print("The root mean squared error is: {:.2f}".format(np.sqrt(mse)))
```

Comment: Please, post a [mre], not the full code. Also, we don't have (and don't want) your dataset, so it would help to have some examples of those negative values, the data and the fit, ideally in a plot so we can see whether the fit _makes sense_. With only the information you are given there can be a lot of reasons to explain that, not related to errors in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the simplest 1d linear regression and let's say the train dataset consists of 1d data and x-y dependency is depicted here:

[image]

While all plotted y-values are positive, you can still choose x-value so that linear regression prediction will show a negative result (for example, if `x=0`). The model is a line (or a plane if dimentiality is higher), the only type of line that doesn't cross x-axis - is a line parallel to x-axis, which is a very specific modelling result.

This is a possible reason for getting negative predictions.

Additionally, from this line
`y = pd.get_dummies(y)`
I am reading that what you actually want - is a classification model, not a regression model. That will solve the negative results problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! ah okay, If remove the get dummies I get this error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Unknown'

Comment: It is because I have a lot of NaN values in my dataset

Comment: `get_dummies` converts categorical (string) column into multiple 0-1 valued columns (depending on the number on unique values). I've translated the name of your target columns from norwegian and it turns out, that the target is price, which should be a number. Converting the price to 0-1 values doesn't make any sense :( and explains the negative values predicted